# Helium Fusion and the Origin of Elements

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

In the fifth of his [Messenger Lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-Km7-6-J81k#t=2182s) Feynman mentions the fact that Carbon-12 has an energy level at 7.82 MeV. He then states that this is what enables the fusion of three Helium-4 ions into Carbon and ultimately enables the production of the other elements. Moreover one can apparently calculate that an energy level of 7.82 MeV is necessary in advance.

Now unfortunately I have almost no knowledge of nuclear physics and therefore do not know how fusion is modelled theoretically. And I do not know if it is hard or easy to estimate that energy level (i.e. it could simply be a matter of if energy conservation allows the process). So my question are:

What goes into this kind of calculation?

and more generally:

What are the current methods for a quantitative (qualitative) understanding of nuclear fusion?

Naively I would model the fusion process by an estimate for the transition amplitude between a $\lvert \text 3{He}\rangle$ state into a $\lvert C\rangle$ state maybe by Fermi's golden rule. This should give you approximately a delta function $\delta(E_f - E_i)$, where $E_f$ and $E_i$ are the energies of the initial and final state. Then you would need to estimate the energy levels of the $3\text{He}$ system and one of them would be approximately at 7.82 MeV.

You can assume in your answers that I took graduate level courses on quantum mechanics and quantum field theory, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1940s and 50s, physicists were trying to understand the formation of carbon-12 in stars.  It was (correctly) proposed that two Helium-4 nuclei first fuse to produce beryllium-8, which then fuses with another Helium-4 to produce Carbon-12.  This is known as the [triple-alpha process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process).  An apparent problem with this explanation was that the ground state of Carbon-12 had too low of an energy for this process to occur to the extent that it does.  [Fred Hoyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Hoyle) proposed in 1954 that there exists an excited state of C-12 just above the combined energy of He-4 and Be-8, meaning just more than 7.6 MeV above the ground state of C-12.  Three years later, such an excited C-12 state was found 7.82 MeV above the ground state.  So Fred Hoyle didn't really calculate the existance of the excited state, he reasoned that since carbon exists, there must be a way to form carbon and therefore such a state must exist.  The excited state is now known as the Hoyle State.

Recently calculation of the Hoyle State from physics princples has been accomplished.  See [Carbon's Hoyle state calculated at long last](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/jan/03/carbons-hoyle-state-calculated-at-long-last).